# How can I show my Gridview first row as Header text?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridView I want to set its first 11 columns as Heading like="NMAT APPLICANT DETAILS". My gridview name is GridView1. How can I set this?

I done it by below mentioned method. Now how can I adjust this heading center of this 11 cells??

My code

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
   {
       GridView HeaderGrid = (GridView)sender;
       GridViewRow HeaderGridRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);
       TableCell HeaderCell = new TableCell();
       HeaderCell.Text = "NMAT APPLICANT DETAILS";
       HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 11;

       HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);
       GridView1.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, HeaderGridRow);
   }
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to have a heading for each column?

Comment: @lzzy,Nope I want only one heading that spans with 11

Comment: What do you mean by "set its first 4 rows"? Do you mean you want a table with two headings one for 4 columns and another for 11 columns?

Comment: @Daniel Cook, plese find my edited question

Comment: your question is still a little confusing.. Maybe you should just use `<h2 align="center">Your Header Text</h2>`

Comment: @lzzy, now my gridview shows heading "NMAT APPLICANT DETAILS" with span of 11 columns. Now this heading align at the left side I want to make it center of the gridvew. Thats all

Answer (score 0):

nothing was there I hust done like below mentioned methode

```
 HeaderCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
```